# Probabilty: Two roots of contrary signs knowing that it has two real roots

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables, each uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$.

I want to compute the probability that the polynomial $T(z)=z^2+Xz+Y,\quad z\in \Bbb{C}$ has two roots of contrary signs knowing that it has two real roots.

Let $A$ be the event $\{X^2\ge4Y\}$ and $B$ the vent that the two roots are of contrary signs. So I need to compute $\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}$ for $A$ I get that is the area under the curve $y=x^2/4$ between $x=-1$ and $x=1$ multiplied by $1/2.$ I get $1/12.$

Not sure how can I continue.

Comment: Hint: Given that you know the roots are real, the event $B$ occurs if and only if [what] about the product of the roots? Then recall Vieta's formula for the product of the roots.

Comment: @quasi if and only if $P(\{x_1x_2>0\}=0$ where $x_i$ is the root. Given a polynomial $X^2-SX+P$ we have that $P=$product of the roots. So here we need to compute the probabilty that $P(Y\le 0)$ which is $1/2,$ right ?

Comment: Also, although $P(B) = 1/2$, that probability is irrelevant.$P(B)$ doesn't appear in your formula for the conditional probability. What you need is the probability of the event $A \cap B$. Look at the region in the $XY$-plane where _both_ $A$ and $B$ occur, and compute the area.

Comment: if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are of contrary signs then we have $x_1x_2<0$ so that $B$ occurs if and only if $P(\{x_1x_2\}>0)=0$. Hum do you mean that is the area under the curve $x^2/4$ between $x=-1$ to $x=0$?

Comment: Almost. The product of the roots is $Y$, right?

Comment: right, I don't see your point... @quasi

Comment: So what is the relevance of $-1 < x < 0$?

Comment: A more natural way to think about $P(B)$ is $P(x_1x_2 < 0)$.

Comment: But $x_1x_2 < 0$ if and only if $Y$ ...? And then don't forget to find the intersection. The actual answer to the problem might seem surprising at first, until you think about it and realize it _had_ to be that.

Comment: @quasi The region where $A$ occur is the are under the curve $y=x^2/3$ between $x=-1$ to $x=1$. if and only if $Y<0.$ So I need to find the region where $A$ occur and such that $Y<0$?

Comment: You meant x^2/4. But yes, that's the intersection you want. Now _look_ at it. Anything surprising?

Comment: @quasi Still, I don't know how to "draw" the region where $Y<0$

Comment: Careful -- under the curve is not just between the curve and the x-axis. It's all points of the region which are under the curve. You probably knew that, but I though I'd warn you anyway, just in case.

Comment: The sample space is a 2x2 square, -1 < X < 1, -1 < Y < 1. What part of that square is the event B? Then just intersect that region with the region for the event A.

Comment: As far as drawing the region where Y < 0, you're in the XY-plane. The variable Y is just the Y-coordinate. I don't see any visualization dilemma.

Comment: @quasi Ok the $XY-$plane, yeah I was a bit confused, $B$ is the $-1<X<1, -1<Y<0,$ and so the area is the area of $B+$ area under the cerve and the $X-$axis.

Comment: Yes, but what about the intersection of A and B? It's an intersection, not a sum. What part of the square is in _both_ A and B?

Comment: @quasi I am very confused because when I said the integral of x^2/4 from x=-1 to x=1 it's betwee the curve and the x-axis,

Comment: So that was wrong too. But now it's easier. Forget the integral. Just shade in the region for the intersection (as part of the 2x2 square). No integration needed. Do you see why?

Comment: Well, you don't need an integral for the intersection (since as you'll see, that region is so simple), but you still need an integral for the P(A) part (after all, you're trying to find a _conditional_ probability)

Comment: Anyway, the final answer for the conditional probability (assuming I calculated it correctly) is 12/13; so you can check my answer against yours.

Comment: @quasi Do you agree for $P(A)=1/24$ ?

Comment: No, the region for A goes all the way down to Y= -1. So P(A) is a lot more than 1/24. In fact, besides missing most of the region for A, you made an arithmetic error on the part you did compute.

Comment: @quasi sorry, 1/12 as I said in my question. Geometrically it's the integral under the curve $x^2/4$ from $x=-1$ to $x=1$ on the $2\times 2$ square. So now I want this region shaded "with" $B$, correct?

Comment: It's not 1/12 either. Do A first. A goes all the way down to Y= -1. What fraction of the square is that? Look at it. Even an estimate will tell you that 1/12 is way too low. The sample space is a 2x2 square. For the event A, shade in the region below the curve. I don't know why you're having such a hard time with this, but hopefully, it's just a one-time confusion.

Comment: @quasi Ok, by definition $P(A)=\lambda(A\cap [-1,1])/\lambda([-1,1])=\frac{\lambda(A\cap [-1,1])}{2}.$ So I need to compute $\lambda(A\cap [-1,1])$ which is an integral, so my error is the fact that is the are under the curve of $x^2/4$ from $x=-1$ to $x=1$?

Comment: For the event A, just shade in the part of in the 2x2 square which is under the curve. Not just down to the x-axis. _All_ the way under. Without Calculus, what's your estimate for the fraction of the square? Then do the needed Calculus.

Comment: This phenomenon is called a blind spot. Ok, P(A) is more than 1/2. Why?

Comment: Also, in your comment where you said "by definition $P(A)=\lambda(A\cap [-1,1])/\lambda([-1,1])=\frac{\lambda(A\cap [-1,1])}{2}$", I have no idea what that expression means. My definition is much simpler. Since the the distribution is uniform, P(A) = (area of the event A) / (area of the square).

Comment: I draw the square and the curve, the area under this curve it's the half of the square (corresponding the $Y<0$) + the area just down the $X-axis$ so that it's $2+1/6=13/6$ and the area of the square is $4$ so we have $13/24.$

Comment: Yes, P(A) = 13/24, now you see it.

Comment: Next the intersection of A and B

Comment: @quasi $B$ is included in $A$ so that we have the probability of the intersection is $P(B)=$are of the half of the square, so that finally $2/13/24=12/13.$

Comment: Bravo! You perservered! (+1)

Comment: You meant (1/2)/(13/24) = 12/13

Comment: @quasi yeah sorry. You took a lot of your time, I am very grateful. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad you worked it out yourself (even if it was a struggle), rather than someone just posting a solution.

Comment: @quasi Such patience would deserve a box of chocolate (a tradition here). Have a nice day.

Comment: One last point. Why is the conditional probability so high? That's perhaps a little surprising, isn't it? But then when you think about it, if Y > 0, that allows the discriminant to go negative, and since -1 < X < 1, the X^2 part of the discriminant can't defend too well against that.

Comment: In any case, I'll let you go. Good work.

Comment: Nice explanation, so for exemple if we want to compute that $T$ has two negatives roots, it's the area under the curve with the $X-$axis / area the square=(1/6)/4=1/24; just looking at geometric point of view. @quasi

Comment: Not quite. For two negative roots, Y has to be positive, but X has to be positive (by Vieta again) to avoid two positive roots.

Comment: @quasi arf, right, silly me. thanks again

Comment: See you in the future. Take care.